# c++, pointer to function + function templates

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, function-pointers

There is a slightly "complicated" code, where the class A stores a pointer to the function (initialized as F1). The function F1 calls F2 and passes F3 as the template parameter.

```
template <typename T>
using cfunction = T(*)(T, T);

template <typename T>
T F3(const T a, const T b) {return a * b;}

template <typename T, typename Function>
T F2(Function func, const T a, const T b) {return func(a, b);}

template <typename T>
T F1(const T a, const T b) { return  F2(F3<T>(a, b), a, b);}

template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
    cfunction <T> X;

    A() : X(&F1) {}
    A(const cfunction <T> &pX) : X(pX) {};
    virtual ~A() {};
};

int main() {
    A<double> b(F1<double>);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the following error occurs:

```
error: 'func' cannot be used as a function
```

Where is the problem? Is there also any way to avoid passing a,b as F2 and F3 parameters? Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
template <typename T>
T F1(const T a, const T b) { return  F2(F3<T>, a, b);}
                                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank for the fast solution :-)